# Tcl file checksum matching

Tags: file, copy, tcl, checksum

I have implemented feature in my tcl/tk project where a file is transferred using fcopy , from windows machine to a VM. Now the problem is the same file is getting copied repeatedly, which is quite unnecessary.

So I have to check if any file with same name already exists in the destination folder. If yes, then I have to make sure that the file content does not match, before aborting the copy procedure. I am aware that check-sum can be used for that but don't know how to implement checksum matching in TCL. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

md5 example

md5.tcl

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

package require md5

set fp [open "md5.tcl" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp

set checksum [md5::md5 -hex $file_data]
puts $checksum
```

output:

```
64F63E82282789ACB8F9271CBF35E8B5
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the UNIX command

```
cksum
```

this can be invoked well with TCL as

```
exec cksum <file>
```

[checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cksum)

Comment: Works fine but solves half of my problem. I have to compare a checksum of a file in windows with a file in linux vm. Where both should generate same checksum for same file.

Answer (score 1):

[Tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/) in the section *Hashes, checksums, and encryption* has the functions that you (probably) need. For example `checksum`.

Comment: I suspect that md5 or (slower) sha1 would be more suitable for this sort of thing. Get them in the same place.